# Power Automate: Parse JSON Error "Invalid type. Expected String but got Object."

Tags: json, power-automate

Im new to Power Automate but it seems I am running into an issue I cant solve. I have replicated from another user: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/how-to-get-an-attachment-provided-via-form-added-to-sharepoint/m-p/1559090

Whenever I go to test the flow, I get this error:

**INPUTS**

```
{
    "content": {
        "webhookId": "******************************",
        "eventType": "ResponseAdded",
        "resourceData": {
            "formId": "****************************",
            "responseId": 4
        },
        "eventTime": "2021-11-24T19:35:59.5832540Z"
    },
    "schema": {
        "type": "string",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "link": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "type": {},
                "size": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "referenceId": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "driveId": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "status": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "uploadSessionUrl": {}
            },
            "required": [
                "name",
                "link",
                "id",
                "type",
                "size",
                "referenceId",
                "driveId",
                "status",
                "uploadSessionUrl"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid type. Expected String but got Object.",
            "lineNumber": 0,
            "linePosition": 0,
            "path": "",
            "schemaId": "#",
            "errorType": "type",
            "childErrors": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone provide any insight?